# UIBarButtonItem image stays blue and not the original color of the image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

How come the icon info.png stays blue and don't comes with the original color of that image? I am using the following code below:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(info:)];
```

Comment: You likely have the Tint color on your view controller set to the default blue.

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't set a tintcolor at all, also not on the Appdelegate.m

Comment: It's set out of the box - you have to unset it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38972264/1908892

Answer (score 76, accepted):

By default, image in UINavigationBar's bar button items is rendered using template mode. You can set it to original.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(info:)];
```

Answer (score 27):

Swift 3:

```
let image : UIImage? = UIImage.init(named: "heart.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 18):

I know this is too late to answer this question but I see  there is a very simple way to solve this issue instead of doing some changes in the code

using Xcode 
Go to the Assets --Select Image --- check Render as and  select  Original image  instead of default property .

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This was the easiest solution

Answer (score 9):

You can it from assets as well. Go to Assets.xcassets >> Select the image that is being used as barbutton item image. Tap on attribute inspector in right side panel. Choose render as to orignial image. It will be default earlier. You will now see colored image.

Comment: This is NOT working with iOS 11 and Xcode 9.4.1. I have images that are configured in the asset catalog to render as original images, but they are still colored silhouettes on the UIToolbarView.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(leftBarButtonPressed))
```

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 2.1+ it would look like this:

```
let image : UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

or simply

```
let image : UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Is there is any other way ? Like special type of image which do not require setting `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal `?

Comment: not afaik - its a limitation of the bar button class

Answer (score 2):

Because the color of barButtonItems in your app is related to the tintColor property on the application's window.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This will make the color red, if I set it to nil it will give back the blue color again.

Comment: Try instantiating the image like this: `UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it... I set the image to it's original state first.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(info:)];
```

Comment: This is clearly explained in Apple's document, "Toolbars":        Bar Button Item Icons

Any bar button in a toolbar can have a custom image instead of text. You can provide this image to your bar button item during initialization. Note that a bar button image will be automatically rendered as a template image within a toolbar, unless you explicitly set its rendering mode to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. For more information, see Template Images.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bar button item tint color from the storyboard. Or color from the image in storyboard.

The color should be your expected color as hex or rgb.