# How to show original image as Bar Button Item on UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm new to iOS app dev. I want to put three `Bar Button Items` with custom image on a `UIToolbar`, but the image displayed on the toolbar is different from its original appearance as shown in picture below:

[My Toolbar Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6CN.png)

[My expectation UIToolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9tkq.png)

If in the `UITabBarController` we can add `withRenderingMode()` as shown below:

```
firstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "xxxxx")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
```

My question is, how to show the original image as `Bar Button Item` on `UIToolbar`?

In my case:

1. I want to change the bottom constraint of the toolbar when Keyboard appear, so the `Bar Button Items` should always be in the `UIToolbar` (not as a `SubView`).
2. Each `Bar Button Items` would be used to segue to other `ViewController`

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can u please show original images which you want  display

Comment: @PiyushSanepara I just added a picture on my post

Comment: see this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827704/navigation-bar-button-image-not-showing-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Step:**

change the tab bar tint color like this :

[image]

**Second Step:**

And change render as for image like this

go to Assets.xcassets then ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PiyushSanepara

Comment: @testios, your 'first step' is actually for TabViewController (not UIToolbar), but your 'Second Step' is worked for my case (UIToolbar) and maybe for all cases. That is what I want! Thanks!